# How to get the facebook native permission dialog on ios6 to ask the user to accept terms and privacy policies of the app?

Tags: facebook, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

Since ios6 users have the possibility to connect their facebook account directly with their ios device. In addition to this facebook updated their ios sdk to allow app developers to ask for basic permissions (does not cover "write permissions") via native dialog as described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/

In case the user uses an older ios version or has not set up the connection between his/her facebook account and ios the facebook sdk still has a fallback in place where it will use the fast-app-switch method instead.

As our app relies on having the user to accept our terms and privacy policies before using our app I was wondering why (in case of the "native login" of the facebook sdk) there is no dialog telling the user that he/she has to accept the app's terms and privacy policies.

Looking at the "old way" via fast-app-switch terms and privacy policies are still part of the dialog and therefor the user has to accept them.

I was wondering if I can change the behavior of the native login to ensure terms and privacy policies will be accepted by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's ARG generally wants you to add EULAs to your app from iTunes Connect rather than displaying them in the app itself. Once the user accepts the agreement they then download the app. I would recommend updating your EULA from there rather than in the app with a disclaimer of "If you're on an older version of iOS" or something similar.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html

Comment: After checking for several solutions there seems to be no other way than adding customized EULAs to the iOS App within iTunes Connect, as you have said. Anyhow it's still unknown to me why in the case of the "native auth/login" (meaning NOT using the fast-app-switch) on ios6 facebook does not require the user to accept the terms/privacy of the actual facebook app.